# Calendrier républicain français: emploi de tous les éléments?

Tags: histoire, terminologie, dates

En lisant le [texte](http://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/conseil-constitutionnel/francais/la-constitution/les-constitutions-de-la-france/constitution-du-24-juin-1793.5084.html) de la *Constitution du 24 juin 1793* (*Première République*,  officiellement nommée *République française*), j'ai noté la mention *Constitution de l'An I* en référence au [*calendrier républicain français*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendrier_r%C3%A9publicain) (1792-1806), évidemment. J'aimerais savoir comment exprimer la date dont il est question (Lundi 24 [juin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messidor) 1793) en utilisant tous les termes du système disponibles; voici une tentative:

> [...]le Sextidi, 6 messidor, décade 28, (de l')an I.

Est-ce que c'est exact? Y a-t-il des règles particulières à suivre lors de l'emploi des termes de ce calendrier (majuscules, ponctuation, chiffre romain, présence/absence de *de l'* devant *an*, etc)? Le contexte pourrait être celui de l'entête d'une lettre(!) ou simplement par exemple dans une phrase quand on relate qu'une personne a prononcé un discours à telle date (le…). Le *Conseil constitutionnel* utilise [*An*](http://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/conseil-constitutionnel/francais/la-constitution/les-constitutions-de-la-france/les-constitutions-de-la-france.5080.html) avec une majuscule par exemple, alors qu'au [*Trésor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/messidor) on a en minuscule (les contextes diffèrent assurément); le [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/messidor) renseigne peu ici. .

Comment: Le découpage en décade est redondant avec le découpage en mois et facile à calculer, c'est pour ça qu'on ne mentionne pas le jour de la décade ni le numéro de la semaine : « 6 messidor an I » dit tout.

Comment: @Gilles Je comprends, merci! C'est seulement après avoir posé la question que l'expression "au long" m'est venue à l'esprit(plutôt que _emploi de tous les éléments_), ce qui n'inclut pas le superflu en soi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'après le « Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale » :

> Dans le calendrier républicain, le quantième du mois se compose de chiffres arabes, le mois en toutes lettres sans majuscule, l'année en chiffres romains grandes capitales :

- *La loi du 18 germinal an III instaura en France l'usage du système métrique.*

> Lorsqu'une date est mentionnée pour évoquer un événement historique et qe l'année n'est pas indiquée, le nom du mois prend une capitale initiale :

- *Le 18 Brumaire préluda au Consulat.*
- *Le 9 Thermidor.*

> Il s'écrira normalement si cette même date n'indique que le jour où s'est produit l'événement sans sans représenter son contenu historique :

- *La journée du 9 thermidor fut fatale à Robespierre.*

Comment: Merci! Peut-être include ce [lien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale) pour fins de référence, en ce 23 nivôse an CCXXIII.